# Adding multiple nodes on different positions on Y axis

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add many nodes on different positions on Y axis. The problem is that for some reason the positions are always (0:0).

I've went through pretty much every SO question related to this but couldn't find answer.

I am generating random number between the maximum and minimum value:

```
func randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: CGFloat, secondNumber: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(arc4random())/CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNumber - secondNumber) + min(firstNumber, secondNumber)

}
```

Now I am trying to add them like this:

```
func addLeftSparks(){

        let randomNumber = Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: leftSparkMinimumY, secondNumber: leftSparkMaximumY)
        print(randomNumber)


        let positions = [CGPoint(x: -275, y: randomNumber), CGPoint(x: -275, y: randomNumber)]
        print(positions) // this is (0:0)

        positions.enumerated().forEach { (index, point) in
            let spriteNode = SKNode()
            spriteNode.position = point
            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spark")

            sprite.name = "Spark"
            spriteNode.addChild(sprite)

        }
    }
```

The thing I am trying to achieve in picture:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, really.

Comment: Might not explain you bug, but shouldn't you be adding `spriteNode` to the scene as well?

Comment: @PauloMattos oh my gosh, you are totally right :D I actually didn't see that :D But why it does add one at time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generated a random number, but you used it twice

```
let randomNumber = Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: leftSparkMinimumY, secondNumber: leftSparkMaximumY)
print(randomNumber)

let positions = [CGPoint(x: -275, y: randomNumber), CGPoint(x: -275, y: randomNumber)]
```

positions is 2 points with the same y, so you will only see one node.  You need to call the random number function for each new random number you want.

(I know you said it was 0,0, but I don't think that's right, so I am ignoring that part -- if you really believe that, put more information in the print statement so that you know you aren't being fooled by some other output)